# datepicker doesn't display

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have verified all links are correct but datepicker doesn't show at all!

```
 <link href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
```

script:

```
<script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $(".Datepicker").datepicker();
       });  
</script>
```

Div:

```
<h2 class="demoHeaders">Datepicker</h2>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Comment: Check console for errors, you will definitely get an idea! your selector doesn't match to your markup, either use class in div or change selector in script

Comment: add a class to the div <div id="datepicker" class="Datepicker"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the jquery selector is wrong

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

you should use the id